# Speeding up a simple LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

Is there any way of speeding up this query:

```
return _database.Countries
   .Include("Accounts")
   .Where(country => country.Accounts.Count > 0)
   .ToList();
```

There are about 70 accounts and 70 Countries, this query takes about 1.5 seconds to execute which is quite long.

EDIT: _database is an EntityFramework model

Comment: What's _database, EF/LinqToSql, some other ORM ?

Comment: Like the other guys have suggested, attach SQL profiler to the Database (if it's live or busy, run select db_id() and use that number as a filter) and look at the SQL that's created. It's a pretty naive select so I imagine your problem is indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could *try* changing the `Where` clause to:

```
Where(country => country.Accounts.Any())
```

... but really your first port of call should be a database profiler. Look at the generated query, and put it into your favourite profiler. Check indexes etc as you would any other SQL query.

Once you've worked out why the generated SQL is slow and what you'd *like* the SQL to look like, then you can start working out how to change your query to generate that SQL.

Comment: I see usage of `Count() > 0` in the context of LINQ all too often. 

I wish the compiler could throw a warning and suggest the use of `Any()` instead. I can't see any good reasons for using `Count() > 0` when we have `Any()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could, use sql profiler to trap the query that is being executed against the database, then using this you could optimise the scenario with indexes on the sql server.